# Piece of cloth in bullets in pistols around the pirate age

Tags: weapons

While seeing the series *Black sails*, there's an episode where two guys face each other in a pistol duel. While preparing the weapons, it is clearly seen that the assistants put a piece of cloth wrapping the bullets. Why is it done?

Comment: So the bullet will fit. Google wadding (IIRC)

Answer (score 9):

Not sure about wrapping a bullet entirely, but muzzleloading firearms do generally require a patch of some kind (typically some sort of cloth or paper) between the ball and the powder. This is because the ball is made to be a slightly smaller diameter than the barrel, so it doesn't get stuck in the barrel while loading. If the gun was fired without a patch, the gases could escape around the ball, greatly reducing the velocity imparted to it. The patch provides a seal to keep the expanding gases trapped behind the ball, so the only way they can escape is by pushing it outwards.

Comment: This is the origin of "*buckskin coats"*; the leather strips were for torn off for padding of the musket balls. Clearly only *dudes* would have ever been caught in a pristine buckskin coat.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Patrick N's answer, the cloth is called "wadding."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadding